# Charset utf-8 not supporting polish lang in cakephp translation

Tags: php, html, cakephp, utf-8, character-encoding

When I put polish special characters

> (Ą, Ć, Ę, Ł, Ń, Ó, Ś, Ź, Ż, ą, ć, ę, ł, ń, ó, ś, ź, ż)

In HTML div it's displaying correctly.
But if I use cakephp function __l() means Its not displaying correclty.

I have checked below things:

I'm using `cakephp2.3`

My html tag
 `<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">`

My ctp file encoded in `utf-8` only.

What is the problem ?

Comment: this line not supporting when posting<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">

Comment: And what is being displayed? Could you show some code/result examples?

Comment: output is "Szczegó?y" Instead of this "Szczegóły"

Comment: So you are not using UTF-8 somewhere but ISO-8859-2 or windows CP1250. Just make sure that you have UTF-8 everywhere and everything should be fine. Or stick with ISO everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Set content type in this your header **(iso-8859-2 standard)**:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
```

Comment: Polish is subset of iso-8859-2 not iso-8859-1.

Comment: @awons: i have mentioned this English, Spanish, French, German, etc. standard not specific....  anyway thank you for sharing and voting..

Comment: This still has nothing to do with the question. ISO-8859-1 will not handle Polish diacritics.

Comment: if its really than than i will remove the wrong answer, but ist OP respond. @awons

Comment: congrats, @jayavel: courtesy to awons. no i am updating the answer with correct iso code... this will help for others... and i also suggest u to accept the answer this action will help to others who also facing same issue.

Comment: For future: i have updated my answer after OP testing and @awons suggested, correct one is **iso-8859-2**